# How to convert nested objects saved in json field in EF core code frist

Tags: c#, json.net, ef-core-2.2

Following is my code snippet.

```
public class MyModelClass
{
    public Matter Matter {get;set;}   // where Matter is json
}

public class Matter
{
    public List<Issue> Issues {get;set;} // list i want to convert on base of types
}

public class Issue
{
}

public class Issue1:Issue
{
}

public class Issue2:Issue
{
}

public class Issue3:Issue
{
}
```

[I have already found solution for json field conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829824/how-to-store-json-in-an-entity-field-with-ef-core)
 but I need to do for nested.

Comment: What i understands from your question you want to make a class using which can automatically filled it's JSON into your Class object?

Comment: Yes something like that . I want  Issues list of Issue containing objects of different issue types like Issue1,Issue2 and Issue3 not List of Issue when i retrieve it from database saved in json field.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand that you need to make the model recognize the nested JSON objects, the only way to work with is to define it like that :

```
public List<type> Issues { get; set; }
```

Comment: what is type here?

Comment: when i used it i used the simple types like string or int ....

Comment: but that's not in my case I required Issues Types

Comment: try that one if it's work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988439/accessing-nested-json-elements-in-mvc-and-razor